# How would you add append to an objects property if it exists conditionally with ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Imagine if there is an object with the following property.

```
var rules = {
 confirmedPassword: 'required|min:4|max:10',
}
```

What I want is this:

```
rules = { rules.confirmedPassword && {...rules.confirmedPassword, rules.confirmedPassword: '|same:password'}}
```

To yield this:

```
rules = {confirmedPassword: 'required|min:4|max:10|same:password',}
```

The reason being, in react I am using the `event.target` in a function to perform a validation later.

So if a user hits the `input` element with `name="confirmPassword"` not only will it have the default of `required|min:4|max:10` but in fact `'required|min:4|max:10|same:password';`

```
validateInputs(event) {
    var { password, confirmPassword } = this.state;
    var { name, value } = event.target;

    var data = {
      password: password,
      confirmPassword: confirmPassword
    };

    var rules = {};
    rules[name] = 'required|min:4|max:10';

    var messages = {
      'password.min': 'Password is too short.',
      'password.max': 'Password is too long.',
      'confirmPassword.min': 'Password is too short.',
      'confirmPassword.max': 'Password is too long.'
    };

    validate(data, rules, messages)
      .then(feedback => console.log(feedback))
      .catch(errors => console.log('foo', errors));

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have the properties stored in an array, and then joining them and/or removing them as you go along.

So for example, say you have 4 inputs, you could have the entire component like so:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    DEFAULT_RULES = ['required', 'min:4', 'max:10'];

    validateInputs(event) {
        const { password, confirmPassword } = this.state;
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        // This can be done this way in ES6, you don't need to do password: password
        const data = {
            password,
            confirmPassword
        };

        let rules = {};
        const rulesArr = this.DEFAULT_RULES.concat('same:password');
        rules[name] = rulesArr.join('|');

        validate(data, rules, messages)
            .then(feedback => console.log(feedback))
            .catch(errors => console.log('foo', errors));

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }
}
```

I may not have the full context but I hope you get what is going on here